# Transfer data from Postgre to Microsoft Sql Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I want to transfer data from Postgre with context `_rentContext` to Microsoft Sql Server with context `_rentContextSql`.

In my program first I check if that record exists in `_rentContextSql` it doesn't add it to the `_rentContextSql` but in the end, when I want to save changes get the error:

> The instance of entity type 'UsersUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 51e4b9f1-e5e3-4bd0-a8f2-513929e1b259}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

```
time = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15);
timeDateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(time);
var postgresUserData = _rentContext.UsersUsers.Where(u => u.DateJoined > time).ToList();
foreach (var user in postgresUserData)
{
    var existing = _rentContextSql.UsersUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(user.Id));

    if (existing == null)
    {
        _rentContextSql.UsersUsers.Add(user);
    }
    else
    {
        _rentContextSql.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
_rentContextSql.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: are `postgresUserData` and `UsersUsers` of the same type?

Comment: Yes, they are the same type

Comment: EF is not designed for migrating data between databases - that's what SSIS is for - but all you need is Polybase (i.e. `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp ( ... ) FROM yourPostgres; INSERT INTO dbo.YourSqlDbTable SELECT * FROM temp`) - anything else is just goiing to cause problems for you.

Comment: I want to implement a job that do this transferring every 15 minutes so i need to use entity framework.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using SQL Agent jobs and a Linked Server.

Comment: *If* you use EF then just don't query the entire user. Only check if it exists by using `Any`. It's also cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new entity instead that is based on `user`, or clone it.

```
if (existing == null)
{
    var newUser = new User
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        // Name = user.Name,
    };
    //var newUser = CloneUtil.Clone(user);

    _rentContextSql.UsersUsers.Add(newUser);
}
else
{
    var newUser = new UsersUser
    {
        //Map
    };
    _rentContextSql.UsersUsers.Update(newUser);
}
```

Comment: I did that but the problem still remains

Comment: What throws the exception? is it the `if` code block or the `else` code block (New or Update)? Eitherway I've updated my answer to handle the updation as well